# Android Unicode characters incorrect

Tags: android, url, fonts, android-webview

In my program I am expecting this:

```
output:array(1) {[0]=>string(59)"అల్లు అర్జున్‌ హీరోగా",
```

But i am getting the output as follows:

[image]

This is my code:

```
try
{
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    String jsonText = EntityUtils.toString(entity, HTTP.UTF_8);

    //tv.setText(jsonText);tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(jsonText));
    // Toast.makeText(this, jsonText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch (Exception e){}
```